# Order of template arguments for a function

Tags: c++, templates

In below code among 2 template arguments, I use one of them implicit and another explicitly:

```
class A {};

template<typename ToType, typename FromType>
ToType CompileTimeCast (FromType pointer)
{
  return (ToType)(pointer);
}

int main ()
{
  A *pA;
  int *pi = CompileTimeCast<int*>(pA); // function invocation
}
```

It works fine. Now, if I swap `ToType` and `FromType` in argument list, compiler throws error as:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘CompileTimeCast(A*&)’
```

Was curious to know, why compiler complains when it knows that both arguments are different at function invocation and one argument is already used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By swapping if you meant this:

```
template<typename FromType, typename ToType> //argument swapped their position!
ToType CompileTimeCast (FromType pointer)
```

Then the argument deduction wouldn't work anymore. Because when you write `CompileTimeCast<int*>`, then compiler would assume that `int*` is always the first argument in the function template argument list. And the second argument would be deduced by the compiler.

Now, you've to explicitly mention the types as:

```
int *pi = CompileTimeCast<A*, int*>(pA); //FromType=A*, ToType=int*
```

Answer (score 3):

When you explicitly specify template arguments, you have to specify them in order, just like you have to specify function arguments in the correct order, even if they are defaulted:

```
int *pi = CompileTimeCast<int*, const int*>(pA);
```

In this example, and assuming your original code, `ToType` is `int*` and `FromType` is `const int*`.  If you explicitly specify only a subset of the template arguments, the compiler is forced to assume that your subset is the first few template arguments, in order.  And *all* of the trailing template arguments *must* be deducible.

Note that for the set of template arguments that the compiler deduces, order doesn't matter.  In your example, *only* `FromType` is deducible.

You have discovered the proper rationale for ordering template arguments:  Order them by decreasing probability that your client want to explicitly specify them in the call of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler should be able to determine type of returned value using function call signature, not using any variable.